# Batch get relative path

Tags: batch-file

Can you get relative file path of the file regarding the execution path in batch script?

What I mean is this:

running batch script in:

```
c:\batchTest\test.bat
```

and there's a file at:

```
c:\batchTest\sub\example.txt
```

how do you in test.bat get the "sub" extracted? because that's relative folder regarding the batch script

I am currently running this batch script but need the relative path for program output (returns full path I need only relative path):

```
for /r %%i in (*.txt) do echo   %%~dpi
```

Comment: Note that the working directory (the one you are executed the batch file from, `%CD%`) is not the same as the parent directory (`%~dp0.`) of the batch script. Anyway, it is not that trivial to get relative paths in a batch file; but what is wrong with absolute paths?

Comment: just need one file to be processed by a program that outputs a new file. But I need a way to maintain the directory structure with the output files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save each string result to a variable, enable delayed expansion, then expand the variable to replace the batch file path with `.\`.

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

For /R "%~p0" %%I In ("*.txt") Do (
    Set "pth=%%~pI"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Set "rel=!pth:%~p0=.\!"
    Echo !rel:~,-1!
    EndLocal
)

Pause
```

*If you want trailing backslahes, then change `!rel:~,-1!` to `!rel!`*

---

If the command is processing files one by one, then I'd suggest you would be wanting the relative file path, not its relative parent directory. If so then this should work for you:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

For /R "%~p0" %%I In ("*.txt") Do (
    Set "pth=%%~pnxI"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Echo !pth:%~p0=.\!
    EndLocal
)

Pause
```

*In this case, you'd replace `Echo !pth:%~p0=.\!` with your command, (using `!pth:%~p0=.\!` as your relative path).*

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear. I have more than one file to process

Comment: Why did you specifically say, ["just need one a file to be processed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63035289/batch-get-relative-path#comment111471425_63035289) then? Anyhow, use the first example in that case! You would obviously replace `Echo !rel:~,-1!` with your command, _(using `!rel:~,-1!` as your relative path)_.

Comment: I meant the program takes one file at time to process

Comment: I have modified the lower example then, this time bacause I'm assuming, if your command is processing files one by one, it would be using the relative file path, not its relative parent directory path.